# Media Items not getting indexed after creation in CMS

Tags: solr, media-library

I am facing issue with `Media file indexing` in `Sitecore 9.2`. When I upload one media file in CMS, then after save the media file is not getting index in `Solr`.

But If I create a `package of Media item` from another instance and install the package, then it is getting indexed and I can search the file in CMS.

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Is the item available in the index after a full rebuild of master index? If not please confirm index update strategy from config

Comment: Yes, after full rebuild, search is working fine. Also, I found that if I detach the media and attach again and save the item, it is getting indexed. So the problem is when we are creating the media item, it is not getting indexed.

Comment: Does the same issue occur on other items in the content tree? If you go to sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx and search for master index, what is the update strategy?

Comment: Also, please check logs folder and look at latest crawling.log and also main log file to see if anything shows at the time of creating the new media item

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky re the issue you mentioned, while I assume your Solr service is functioning properly.

To verify this, please ensure that there are no `errors` or exceptions in the Solr logs.

If there are no Solr error messages, the problem may be on the `Sitecore end`. Therefore, please check the Sitecore logs to see if there are any errors or exceptions.

To eliminate other potential issues, I suggest that you first try to `rebuild` all indexes to see if the `master index` is broken, which can sometimes happen.

After completing the above steps, please try to reproduce the issue again to confirm if it works correctly.

If the issue persists, I recommend raising a `support ticket` to the Sitecore team for further assistance, especially if it's urgent.

Comment: I found that if I detach the media and attach again and save the item, it is getting indexed. So the problem is when we are creating the media item, it is not getting indexed.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding part or all of the index? If any error ? @KoushikMukherjee

Comment: I did, no error and all getting indexed after rebuild. Again when I create a new Media item, it didn't indexed in Solr.

Comment: Did you just upgrade it from an earlier version of Sitecore? or is it a clean instance?

Comment: @KoushikMukherjee Could you please also check if the native search query in solr Dashboard to filter the media item works? If it is working and return the correct result , it might be the Sitecore end issue.
Also please refer to the link https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/the-search-and-indexing-log-files.html to check if  indexing process works as expected.

Comment: Newly created media items are not indexed in Solr and in search they are not appearing. Only if I detach the media and attach again and save the item, it is getting indexed and showing in Solr.

Comment: Hi @KoushikMukherjee, that's really weird and abnormal, the best and more straight-forward way is to reinstall Sitecore and Solr instance with a cleanup.